# Access violation while copying a string of wchar from network packet

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t

I'm programming game server and it uses unicode since I'm in Korea.
The problem is that I can't copy wchar string from packet.

I checked `wcsncpy_s(chat, 100, inChat.c_str(), inChat.length());` this works fine but something like this doesn't work.

```
wchar_t strId[10];  // I'm trying to copy L"player11" here.    
wcsncpy_s(
            strId,
            10,
            (WCHAR*)(buffer[2]),  // buffer[0] : packet size, buffer[1] : packet type
            9                     
        );
```

[Memory view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKhcR.png)

I checked so many times to figure out what I've done wrong but I have no idea what is wrong about it.

It throws the same exception every time.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF20DFE5A0 (ucrtbased.dll) in SimplestMMORPG-Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000070.
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to specify offset from the `buffer`'s beginning, instead of trying to interpret `buffer[2]` as memory address:

```
wcsncpy_s(
            strId,
            10,
            (WCHAR*)(buffer + 2),
            9                     
        );
```

Because: given that `buffer` is declared as `char* buffer` (or `std::byte* buffer`) that is buffer contains a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_and_C++) to some memory (shown on screenshot), `buffer[2]` takes 3-rd element from the buffer. `buffer[2]` has type `char`, and type `char` is incompatible with 3rd parameter of `wcsncpy_s`. (From the memory view 3-rd byte is 0x70. Then 0x70 was passed as third parameter to `wcsncpy_s`, which expects 3rd parameter to be a memory address, and it tries to read from `0x70` memory address, and fails, that's why error message was `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000070`)

Instead you need to calculate an address of that string inside buffer, as `buffer + 2`, `buffer + 2` has type `char*`. `wcsncpy_s` expects exactly `char*` as a third parameter.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. One more question. Can you explain why my solution doesn't work and this one works fine?

Comment: @JeongminHeo , I've updated my answer, hope it's more descriptive now.

Comment: I made a foolish mistake...I've never thought it'd be something like that. Now everything is clear. Thanks for the help!